# Text Field & Select Field Combination (Javascript + Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, select, text, field

To give you some idea, if you have a Google Account go to GMail and try to add or edit a contact. I am looking to get almost the same exact effect as those text/select fields. It would also be nice if this library also made it easy to give that Add another option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pointing to the edit option you get when you click on the contact name, then please look for plugins providing in-place edits. (Example - [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html))